# Chat Bot for Facebook Messaging

Tags: facebook, chat, bots

I would love your opinion on the possibility and then any help creating a Facebook Messaging Chat Bot. The idea behind this would be to switch this on, targeting a specific person and the program would be able to hold a small conversation with the selected person.

I know it would be difficult creating a chat bot from scratch so I was thinking of using an open source personalized bots such as http://www.pandorabots.com/ or http://www.personalityforge.com/. The software would then take a response from the person who we want to message and run it though the website. Then use the reply from the website back into the chat. Repeating the process to hold a small conversation. In areas where the website does not know how to answer a question the user would be alerted and would be able to send the message themselves.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Piotr,

Take a look at this Medium article about setting up an example Facebook bot:

https://medium.com/@matthewericfisher/facebook-bots-for-fun-and-profit-490245c3797c#.awbki3omq

The example DMS Software bot is at:

https://m.me/dynamicmemorysolutions

The source is at:

https://github.com/matthewericfisher/fb-robot

--Matt